# How many systems a given rack can hold

Tags: cassandra

I am getting trained on Apache casssandra, where terms like nodes and racks are quite predominantly used. I understand that a rack is to hold n number of systems or nodes. But was wondering whether there is any upper limit to it, like a rack can hold this many systems.

It was just for the sake of understanding, if any one knows the answer or any points to make on this, please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limit to the number of systems in a rack - racks are used to balance replicas within a datacenter, but are not bounded (though certainly, you're limited to a reasonable number of nodes in a datacenter, typically around 1000).

Rack awareness can be tricky, especially if you have fewer racks than your replication_factor, or if your racks are of uneven sizes. Adding a rack after the fact, in particular, can cause significant problems - many operators disable rack awareness to avoid edge cases.